# Keybindings to start Thunderbird and Rhythmbox in Ubuntu 20.04: How to know them and how to disable them?

Tags: thunderbird, shortcut-keys

Sometimes I unwittingly do some key combo that fires up Thunderbird or Rhythmbox in Ubuntu 20.04. How can I know what's the keybinding triggering these actions and how can I disable it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Several keyboard shortcuts can be seen (and changed) in Settings - Keyboard.

What you may experience is the effect of the <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>Number</kbd> shortcuts. By default, <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd> will launch (or switch to if it is already running) to the first application on your dock. <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>2</kbd> switches to the second application on the dock.

In Ubuntu 21.10, the only way to delete (or change) these keyboard shortcut is through dconf-editor, or using commands:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.shell.keybindings switch-to-application-1 "['']"
```

Repeat that for `-2` up to `-9` to remove all bindings. Replace `set` by `reset` and leave out the last argument (`"['']"`) to reset to default.

Comment: This is the answer, thank you! Only one thing: do you think the inner `''` is needed or "[ ]" will do?

Answer (score 0):

Settings -> Keyboard -> Customize shortcuts ->
find yours (i suppose in -> Launchers) (or in -> Custom Shortcuts)